# I can't setup docker-compose containers with an ipv6 that depend on each other

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ipv6

I'm looking for a solution where docker-compose and make 2 docker containers communicate nicely and that can have an ipv6 address that can bridge to a outside address.

- Host OS: CentOS 7
- docker version: 17.12
- docker-compose version: 1.9.0

I have a docker compose file that works for ipv4 addressing using the `network_mode: "service:postgres"` as follows:

```
version: "2.1"
services:
    myApp:
        image: myApp:latest
        volumes:
                - myApp_home:/home/tio/
        network_mode: "service:postgres"
        command: /root/run.sh
        depends_on:
             - postgres
        restart: always

    postgres:
        image: postgres:9.6
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
        volumes:
            - myApp_sql:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "443:443"
volumes:
    myApp_home:
    myApp_sql:
```

With this configuration, my application can connect to postgres, but I cannot ping its IPv6 address and it cannot ping out over IPv6, but it *can* ping an IPv4 address.

When I use `network_mode: bridge` like in the configuration below, pinging over IPv6 works in both directions, but postgres is no longer available on localhost, so my application needs to know the IP address of the postgres container.

```
version: "2.1"
services:
    myApp:
        image: myApp:latest
        volumes:
            - myApp_home:/home/tio/
        network_mode: bridge
        command: /root/run.sh
        depends_on:
            - postgres

    postgres:
        image: postgres:9.6
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
        volumes:
            - myApp_sql:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "443:443"
volumes:
    myApp_home:
    myApp_sql:
```

I would like to be able to ping out from the container over IPv6 *and* connect to postgres on localhost. Since this works with IPv4, I think it's either a bug or I'm missing something in my configuration.

Is this a bug in docker, docker-compose, or is there some configuration where I can get `network_mode: "service:postgres"` to also allow pinging over IPv6?